# error when typing npm start ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, npm

I've been using npm and it kept throwing errors so I reintsalled nodejs, npm, and express and this is what I get when I start npm. Seems that it keeps reading a legacy file, how can I fix it?

npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
0

Comment: Is it safe to say you didn't read contents of /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

Comment: Get Node 4.3 installed from nodesource